# Return earliest date in Power BI column based on other column value

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a column that returns the earliest date from the column 'update' when the column 'task' has the value 'A', for each ID.

My context is : the table i have is a history of every modifications done on a database of about 10 columns, but here I want to focus on when the task was started, so the earliest date. When the task A is done for an ID, column 'Task' takes value B, meaning task B has now started.

Table :

| ID | Task | update (dd/mm/yyyy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2023 |
| 1 | B | 02/01/2023 |
| 2 | A | 03/01/2023 |
| 1 | A | 05/01/2023 |

Result :

| ID | Task | update (dd/mm/yyyy) | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| 1 | B | 02/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | A | 03/01/2023 | 03/01/2023 |
| 1 | A | 05/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |

The end goal is to do that with each task, then only have one row per ID, like so :

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 | 02/01/2023 |
| 2 | 03/01/2023 |  |

I first tried using only filters, so filter by Task value first, then order date descending, then keep the first row only but it doesn't work.

On another post I saw this dax but I struggle to make it work for me.

```
A = 
VAR MinUpdate =
   CALCULATE (
     MIN ( 'Table'[Update]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Task]="A"))

RETURN
    IF (('Table'[Update] == MinUpdate), 'Table'[Update])
```

It only returns the earliest date in the whole table rather than by ID.

I am a beginner in DAX and I don't really know how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to do it in Power Query M language. To do so, you can select your table then "Edit Query". Add a step in your table query in which you add the following code:

```
Table.Pivot(
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"ID", type text}}), 
        List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"ID", type text}})[Task]), 
       "Task", 
       "update ", 
        List.Min)
```

What i'am using here is the pivot fucntion, you can also use the graphic tool to implement it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it's working well ! From there how can I group my rows to keep only one row with the dates of each task ? Right now if column A has a date, column B is null

Comment: I didn't understand your question, normally after applying this step you should have one row by ID, and columns would be your Tasks values